# Package conflict during rpm install of node

Tags: node.js, rpm, centos7

I am trying to do an rpm install of Node, but it is failing with the following error:

```
[xxxx@xxxxxxxx xxxx]# rpm -ivh Node-v0.10.33-RHEL.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        file /usr/bin from install of Node-v0.10.33-RHEL.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
        file /usr/lib from install of Node-v0.10.33-RHEL.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
```

I have been looking around the internet for the past two days but all the errors similar to mine (conflict with filesystem package) had been due to issues with the rpm package. In my case, I can rule that out as I have previously used the same rpm for node installation on other VMs successfully.

My user has root privileges and my OS is CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Comment: it looks like the rpm wasn't properly packaged; because it provides the directories "/usr/bin" and "/usr/lib". You might considering just using the `--force` option; but I agree that that isn't very nice... other solution is to repackage yourself or look for another rpm.